# how to call the method in the same dict using python 

Tags: python, dictionary

this is my code :

```
a= {'u': lambda x: x*x,'b':self.u(5)}

print a['u'](5)
print a['b']
```

but it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 6, in <module>
    a= {'u': lambda x: x*x,'b':self.u(5)}
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

so how to print a['b']

thanks

Comment: this is not javascript. use a real class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thought: why aren't you using a class instead?

```
class A:
    def u(x):
        return x*x
    def b():
        return self.u(5)
a = A()
```

Second thought: if you really must do it with a dictionary (but really, must you?), try this:

```
a = {'u': lambda x: x*x}
a['b'] = a['u'](5)
```

Since you're not implementing a method of an object, there is no `self`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to do this but it is not possible, instead you can assign to dict one by one e.g.

```
a= {'u': lambda x: x*x}
a['b'] = a['u'](5)
```

or first define the function and then use it e.g.

```
f = lambda x: x*x
a= {'u': f, 'b': f(5)}
```